# Several <pathspec> in one git command

Tags: git

How to run git command with several pathspecs? For example, I want to look diffs of three different file extensions:

```
$ git diff -- *.ts | *js | *.map
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close.  Try:

```
git diff -- '*.ts' '*js' '*.map'
```

In your form, you'd be telling the shell to pipe data from `git diff -- *.ts` into `*js` (whatever happened to be picked up with that glob) and piped into `*.map`.  That's definitely not what you want.

The form I give above is the correct way to say show me all *.ts, *js, and *.map files that have change.  You need the quotes around the globs to keep the shell from expanding them, so that git can see what you are actually asking for.